# Layout Manger to Freely place your objects

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am a self-taught java developer and I use IntelliJ IDEA for Java. Recently I saw a video on youtube in which the guy was using NetBeans and in his JFrame form, he was able to freely place his objects like JButton, JTextFeild, JLabel, etc. I am not able to figure out how to do that. In IntelliJ IDEA I found several layout managers such as Border, Card, Grid, Bag, etc. but none of them gave the desired result. can somebody please tell me how can I get a layout manager in which I can freely place all my objects and also freely resize them without any restrictions? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What you saw in the youtube video was probably a Swing GUI Designer (I think NetBeans does have one). But to learn Java Swing, you should not be using GUI Designers. The best way for you to learn it and write good, maintainable Swing code is to do it yourself.

Comment: The [Java Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) should be a good starting point and teach you all the basics needed.

Comment: *"self-taught .. saw a video on youtube"* YouTube videos are no way to learn programming. Visit the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) trail in the tutorial and learn how to use layout managers. That 'drag and drop' video you saw is teaching bad practices.

Comment: As others have advised, you can use setLayout(null) or a JScrollPane with a Container with a null layout inside it. How as also advised, it is good practice to use layout managers so that your frame can repaint properly when it is resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swing every component `extends Container`. That means that every component can have nested components (they all have `add(Component)` method). However, not all of them support the layout-ing of nested components.

What I want to say is, that you can add a component to a `JButton`, but a `JButton` is not capable of showing its nested components.

So, in order to have nesting, we use the components - containers that support the orientation of their nested components.

These components are all windows (`JFrame`, `JDialog`, etc...) and `JPanel`s. There some others that support layout-ing a specific type of nested components. For example a `JMenu` is capable of showing `JMenuItem`s properly.

Now, these "top-level"/empty containers are [using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) in order to align-show their nested components. Based on the container's layout manager, the components are shown.

This is why you can't "freely" place the components into a `JFrame`. Because its Layout Manager is taking care of the components will be placed. So, what you are looking for, is to change its LayoutManager (use `setLayout` method) to one that allows you to freely place the components.

Guess what? There is no such layout manager. Simply because, it would have nothing to do/calculate since you are taking care the layout of the components. So, in order to achieve the "free" component layout, you must use `jframe.setLayout(null);`. In order to layout the components after it, you will have to use `componentInsideJFrame.setBounds(...)` and give it constant coordinates /dimension.

This is bad practice. A very bad one when it comes to UI. Giving a component static coordinates and dimension is bad. There are some questions you have to ask yourself.

What if user resizes the window? If the window is `301x301`, the center of it, is at `(150,150)`. So you place a component at `(150,150)`. Ok it works. Now user resizes the window and makes it `501x501`. The center is now standing at `(250,250)`. But the component is staying at `(150,150)`. There is the solution of `setResizable(false)`, to this kind of problems, but how often have you used "uncapable of resizing" applications? What if user wants to resize it?

I hope you get it and understood what I am trying to say.

By using layout managers, you are solving this kind of problems easily, since the layout manager will take care of the resize and calculate the new center.

Yes. I know it feels weird, but all these youtube tutorials are not teaching you the correct way to make Swing GUIs. (This is a conversation for another day, I guess)

I truly suggest you read the tutorials of Swing documentation in order to get some ideas of how layout managers work. You will really benefit from those.

Finally, I suggest you to leave outside the whole "gui-builder-tool" thing. They seem to help you building your GUI, but they are adding so much additional/useless code and most of the times they are "bad UI creation" prone. Try to code the GUI by yourself.

At first, this sounds a bit harsh, but you can always run your application and see the result of the GUI. After some mistakes, you will finally be able to imagine the GUI result by only seeing the `container.setLayout(..)` and `container.add(...)` lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the time and effort you have put to answer my query, I really appreciate your effort, thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please check out this video and tell me how has he done this and is it a good practice? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He-1O8Pa4SE&list=PLlGZc17KPrVCGRKtgbdvnGshN8AePlqpd&index=1

Comment: The guy whos videos I watched also used some external software: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xwr9n5-L7Ro